# primefaces menubar using model does not show submenus and items

Tags: spring-mvc, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

am using jsf2 and primefaces 3.5 spring webflow.
My index page does not show the menubar (created by a model) submenus and items. although the pages on webflow show the menu bar.

my code is as follows
**root-context**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/" location="/resources/**"/>

<faces:resources />


<import resource="controller.xml"/>
<import resource="webflow.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.testapp"/>

<bean id="faceletsViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">      
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView"/>      
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />      
    <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />   
</bean>
```

**Webflow**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.scope.ScopeRegistrar"/>

<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>          
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>          
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>   

<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="facesFlowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/pages">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>

<faces:flow-builder-services id="facesFlowBuilderServices" development="true" />

<bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">      
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" /> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

**Controller**

```
    <mvc:view-controller path="/index" view-name="index" />
    <mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.testapp.Controller"/>
```

thanks

the index

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="/WEB-INF/layout/layout.xhtml"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<p:menubar model="#{mainMenuModel.model}"/>

<ui:define name="content">
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

the template

```
<h:body styleClass="body">
        <h:form id="contentForm">

            <ui:insert name="menu"/>

            <ui:insert name="content"/>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Comment: And you've shown everything but the affected index page here. Why?

Comment: sorry about that but i've added them